# In karate, how do i find the length os json objject (map)?

Tags: karate

i have a response like this:

```
{
  "Team:14051898": null,
  "59a0a29fe4b04de817c2a635": {
    "eid": "abc123",
    "name": "Chris"
  },
  "57dc07aae4b00768fe90cbf7": null,
  "Team:15199": {
    "eid": "abc123",
    "name": "Christin"
  },
  "59c53c15e4b066f69a1180d4": {
    "eid": "abc123",
    "name": "Michae"
  },
  "589cace8e4b0b32006e03299": {
    "eid": "abc123",
    "name": "Jay"
  },
  "59e0e2eae4b0c0e023297a2f": null
}
```

i need to find the length (no:of teams) in it. I tried using:

```
* string expression = 'Object.keys(response).length'
* def result = karate.eval(expression)
* print result
```

And also $.length and few other options. Please help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways for example using the `karate.forEach()` but this is the simplest:

```
* def json = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }
* def map = karate.toBean(json, 'java.util.HashMap')
* def count = map.size()
* match count == 3
```

EDIT - there is now a [`karate.sizeOf()`](https://github.com/intuit/karate#karate-sizeof) API that works for both arrays and objects

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way using javascript is:

```
Scenario: MyTest
  * def countKeys = function (obj) {return Object.keys(obj).length;}
  * def response =
    """ {
      "Team:14051898": null,
      "59a0a29fe4b04de817c2a635": {"eid": "abc123","name": "Chris"},
      "57dc07aae4b00768fe90cbf7": null,
      "Team:15199": {"eid": "abc123", "name": "Christin"},
      "59e0e2eae4b0c0e023297a2f": null
    }"""
  * match 5 == countKeys(response)
```